# Data load from Kafka not working in Druid

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, druid

Recently I setup Apache Druid using Docker and now it is up & running. I am able to access it via [http://localhost:8888](http://localhost:8888/). I have setup Apache Kafka on my local machine with zookeeper. What I need is to connect Druid to Kafka. I have enabled the ***druid-kafka-indexing-service*** extension on Druid and set ***advertised.listeners*** as ***PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092*** in Kafka.
But Druid is giving

[image]

> Error: Request failed with status code 500

I  am new to Docker, Druid as well as Kaka so If you guys can show me any other points I may have miss, That would be very helpful. This my kafka config on Druid

[image]

Comment: _setup Apache Druid using Docker_ - Then `localhost` refers to Druid, and not Kafka.. I suggest reading the Docker documentation on how network communication between containers works, and make sure that you setup Kafka to not advertise itself as localhost for other containers to connect to it

Comment: Adding this link for good explanation of what is happening to you, https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @OneCricketeer why comment and not answer?

Comment: @RanLupovich Because the Docker Compose/commands were not provided to tell what the correct answer should be

Comment: Great Thanks OneCricketeer & RanLupovich  for your guidance. Your comments and link was a huge help. I still dunno if it's the proper way, but I was abled to resolved it.
I installed kafka on docker as well. but issue was still there, Then I created a docker network and bind all my modules with it. my app, database, kafka & druid. Also used container names to dbhost name & advertise listener. Since druid and kafka now in same docker network, I used kafka:9092 as the bootstrap server. Again many thanks for you both!

Comment: I referred this one as well https://www.javainuse.com/devOps/docker/docker-mysql